# If condition on Django html Template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

jobseqno=P567890

```
<td>
{% if jobseqno|first:"P" %}** <a href="{{ url }}{{ jobseqno }}" target="_blank">{{ jobseqno}}</a>{% endif %}
</td>
```

The above attached code doesn't work please help me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this with:

```
{% if 'P' == jobseqno|first %}
    …
{%endif %}
```

If you are however filtering a `QuerySet`, you should filter it in the database query, so in the *view*, not the template.